# An anomaly concerning the "Closed" banner for closed questions: Is its appearance variable?

Tags: discussion, bug

[What is a good source for risqué content that's not pornographic?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/113251/what-is-a-good-source-for-risqu%c3%a9-content-thats-not-pornographic)

The above question was closed. When I looked just now, the **Closed** banner looked liked this

[image]

That is not a problem in itself, however I also noticed that a comment from two hours earlier said the following

> The close banner explicitly states that "Recommendation questions
> asking for movies/TV-shows or resources to locate or watch movie/TV
> content are off topic". – Jenayah 2 hours ago

[image]

**Question**

I have no reason to doubt what Jenayah said in their comment, so what's going on?

(a) The banner appears differently to different people

(b) The banner changed over time

(c) Something else

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a). I believe it works like this:

- People with the close-vote privilege (like Jenayah) see the full closed banner, with the close reason and the list of close-voters. The OP also sees this regardless of their reputation.
- People who don't have the close-vote privilege (like yourself) only see the generic message in your screenshot.

This change was made [back in December 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/461068) but I'm not sure of the reasoning behind it.

---

*Late edit*

As the post in question was deleted on 7 April, you also now need high rep to be able to see it at all. I think lower rep users will just get a 404 - Page not found.
For future readers, this is the close [& delete] banner that high rep users can see on that question. Names have been redacted.

[image]

Comment: this is a different issue, but why does it show up as "off topic" rather than "duplicate"?  If there is an opinion that a different question may already contain answers to this one, why wouldn't be closed "duplicate" and allow anyone else who maybe interested in the same question to see the referenced question (and its answers)?

Comment: I don't think it was closed as a duplicate. It was considered an ID question and closed as off-topid.

Comment: @CGCampbell I think grovkin is referring to [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9301/46980), that's linked to in the full closed banner for recommendation questions. What he's suggesting is that, if we're going to link people to that question in the close banner anyway, then it would be better to close recommendation questions as a duplicate of that question, rather than having a separate close reason. That would, of course, require a separate Meta discussion.